# What is the lowest HD creature outsider with at will invisibility?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, monsters, invisibility

A wizard using planar binder. Malconvoker so prefers evil outsiders. 
What's the lowest HD you need to get at will invisibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer covers *Monster Manuals I* through *V* and the *Fiend Folio*. I didn't hunt through additional material.

#### HD 2

The filth imp (*Fiend Folio* 100) has, among others, the following spell-like ability: at will—[*invisibility*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsHtoL.html#invisibility) (self only). Because of their Hit Dice, three such creatures can be bound using the 5th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*lesser planar binding*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#lesser-planar-binding) [conj] (*PH* 260-1).

#### HD 3

The [imp](http://dndsrd.net/monstersDtoDe.html#imp-devil) (*Monster Manual* 56) and the [quasit](http://dndsrd.net/monstersDtoDe.html#quasit-demon) (*MM* 46) have, among others, the following spell-like ability: at will—[*invisibility*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsHtoL.html#invisibility) (self only). Because of their Hit Dice, two such creatures can be bound using the spell *lesser planar binding*. Useful if confined to printed creatures in the core rules exclusively.

#### HD 5

The maurezhi (*FF* 50–1)—a ghoul-like demon—has, among others that are even more impressive, the following spell-like ability: at will—[*invisibility*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsHtoL.html#invisibility). It's also within the HD limit of the spell *lesser planar binding*.

#### HD 6

The [fiendish](http://dndsrd.net/monstersEtoF.html#fiendish-creature) (*MM* 107–8) [ogre mage](http://dndsrd.net/monstersOtoR.html#ogre-mage) (*MM* 200) has, among others, the following spell-like ability: at will—[*invisibility*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsHtoL.html#invisibility). It also can be bound using the spell *lesser planar binding*. The application of templates is typically the domain of the DM, but this creature has the advantage of being possible according to the core rules.

#### HD 9

The [couatl](http://dndsrd.net/monstersBtoC.html#couatl) (*MM* 37–8) has, among a variety of others, the following spell-like ability: at will—[*invisibility*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsHtoL.html#invisibility). Its Hit Dice means that it can be bound using the 6th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*planar binding*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#planar-binding) [conj] (*PH* 261) with 3 Hit Dice leftover for a also binding an imp or quasit (if the DM allows a different creatures to be called and bound with a single casting). The pair probably won't get along. Again, useful if confined to printed creatures in the core rules exclusively.

#### HD 15

A xerfilstyx (*FF* 59–60)—an aquatic, tauric, winged slug-devil—has, among a host of others, the following spell-like ability: at will—[*greater invisibility*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsHtoL.html#greater-invisibility). Its Hit Dice means that it can be bound using the 8th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*greater planar binding*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#planar-binding) [conj] (*PH* 261) with 3 Hit Dice leftover for also binding an imp or quasit (if the DM allows a different creatures to be called and bound with a single casting). It will get along fine with the imp but not the quasit, which it will probably torture then eat at the earliest opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

The pixie (1RHD) has greater invisibility as a special quality, but is always NG.

Comment: Originally, my answer had a whole 'graph about summoning a celestial pixie for its supernatural ability *greater invisibility*, but I really didn't think any DM would allow the celestial pixie to use that ability on another creature. (The rules don't say that it *can't*, but they also give no indication that it *can* — so DM's discretion, I guess?) I'll upvote this if you want to make a stronger case for it, though. (It needs to be celestial  — or another appropriate template — so that it can be called and bound with a *planar binding* spell.)